# count regular expression using substr_count

Tags: php

How to count all the special characters on a string ?
example:

```
$sample_string = "!!~~Sample string";
echo substr($sample_string, special character);
```

so the output will be 4.

Comment: Is it possible that the special chars are distributend randomly in the string? Not all sequentially at then beginning?

Answer (score 3):

By Regex

```
$sample_string = "!!~~Sample string";

preg_match_all("/\W/",$sample_string,$match);

echo count($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

$pattern = '/[!@#$%^&*()]/'  // will match one occurrence of any symbol inside the []

```
int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Perform a global regular expression match against a string. Searches subject for all matches to the regular expression given in pattern and puts them in matches in the order specified by flags.

After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `preg_replace_callback` function along with `closure` like as

```
$sample_string = "!!~~Sample string";
$count = 0;
preg_replace_callback('/[^\h\w]/', function($m)use(&$count) {
    $count++;
}, $sample_string);
echo $count;//4
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/448839)